# Array of objects without default constructors on the stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I can achieve the functionality I need using option 3, however I would like to investigate whether it is possible to create the array on the stack instead.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

struct NotDefaultConstructable
{
    NotDefaultConstructable(int val){};
};

int main()
{
    //std::array<NotDefaultConstructable, 5> aA;    // Fails to compile. [On stack]

    //std::vector<NotDefaultConstructable> aV(5); // Fails to compile. [On heap]

    std::vector<NotDefaultConstructable> aV; // Compiles. [ On heap]
    aV.reserve(5);
}
```

Comment: It compiles because `aV` is an _empty_ vector. `aV.reserve(5)` does not make it an vector of 5  `NotDefaultConstructable`s

Comment: Option 3 is creating an empty "array". It contains no objects. So it isn't clear what you're after exactly.

Comment: @Harry clang++ compiler

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, so how do I reserve 5 * sizeof(NotDefaultConstructables) on the stack, and make pushed objects use that space

Comment: @juanchopanza I want the same as option 3 but instead of new objects living on the heap, I want them to live on the stack

Comment: If you want a vector of your objects, each object needs to be constructed some way. e.g `aV.push_back(NotDefaultConstructable(42));`. The objects will live in the `aV` vector which in turn lives on the stack.

Comment: The failure of the first two to compile is unrelated to whether objects are in "heap" or "stack".   It's that both rely on being able to default-construct the elements (i.e. initialise members with a constructor that accepts no arguments).   The sample that does compile doesn't attempt to construct any objects.

Comment: @Jabberwocky "The objects will live in the aV vector which in turn lives on the stack."
The vector may live on the stack, but all the objects in that stack will live on the heap

Comment: @Harry `NotDefaultConstructable aV[5]` won't work either: https://godbolt.org/z/8MvxTo

Comment: @Peter Yes I agree. My point is I know how to not construct the objects by using option 3, however by using that option when it does come to storing the new objects they are stored on the heap.

Comment: After reading all the comments, I'm still confused; how would you make sure the constructor/destructor of these objects are invoked? The lifetime of the instances is unclear in your original question.

Comment: your options 1,2 and 3 are all very different, hence you need to explain what functionality you want to achive. From the code alone it is not clear. (option 3 is not creating any `NotDefaultConstructable` objects btw)

Comment: @AidanGallagher I think the lifetime management of your objects will be terrible like that; https://godbolt.org/z/54q9o1 - that's a way of doing what you want, but you need to explicitly construct and destruct the objects yourself

Comment: @AidanGallagher Maybe you should tell us what you're _actually_ trying to achieve. Read this: [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I have created a circular buffer container class. However I can only store objects which have a default constructor because my underlying container class is `std::array`. I would like to have the objects stored on the stack (so no using `std:vector`) and I would the container to be able to store objects without a default constructor.

The circular buffer : https://github.com/aidan-gallagher/concurrent-containers/blob/develop/SearchRingBuffer/SearchRingBuffer.h

Comment: `boost::static_vector<NotDefaultConstructable, 5>` is the stack based equivalent.

Comment: Why would you "like to have the objects stored on the stack"?   There are very few real-world samples where that is worth doing deliberately by any means other than creating an array with either static or automatic storage duration.      A container can't store objects that have not been constructed (since the elements will not exist before their construction) so, if the class does not have a default constructor, you need to specify what constructor (for the elements) to call when defining the array.

Comment: @Peter I'm mainly asking for my own learning/exploration at this stage. It could be important in certain scenarios such as embedded environment that doesn't have a free store or latency penalty for heap allocation is too expensive

Comment: I will look into using placement new on some buffer already allocated on the stack.

Comment: Learning/exploration is fine, but your belief that you need to worry about embedded systems without free store is out of date by decades now.   If you're working on a system where latency penalty related to memory allocation matters, allocating on the stack is rarely a preferred alternative - there isn't some magic that means stack allocation avoids latency concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the fact that OP mentioned looking into using placement new, I wanted to make a full example of using a stack allocated array as memory for dynamically constructed objects.

Using this method, you can allocate stack memory without initializing it with instances. The problem, however, is that you have to monitor the object lifetime for each instance yourself. In this example, I construct all of them and can then simply assume that all of them have to be destroyed, however monitoring how many instances are alive and should be destroyed is quite messy.

This is why [dfrib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64911868/2047576)'s answer is much more suitable in your situation, as it allows you to allocate the memory on the stack using `std::array<std::optional<Type>, 5>` and assign instances later. Object lifetime will also be managed for you, so is much more advisable.

### Example 1: Placement New:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct NotDefaultConstructable {
    int Value;

    NotDefaultConstructable(int val) : Value(val) {
        std::cout << "constructed: " << Value << "\n";
    };

    ~NotDefaultConstructable(){
        std::cout << "destructed: " << Value << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    // allocate enough memory on the stack for 5 instances 
    char aV[sizeof(NotDefaultConstructable) * 5];
    
    // get a pointer to the first NotDefaultConstructable in that array 
    auto avArray = static_cast<NotDefaultConstructable*>(static_cast<void*>(&aV[0]));

    // use placement new to construct each instance 
    for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        new (&avArray[i]) NotDefaultConstructable((i + 1) * 2);

    // do stuff with the instances 
    for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        std::cout << "instance: " << avArray[i].Value << "\n";

    // destruct them all manually, this is what makes placement new a little 
    // cumbersome. I would advise to use std::optional instead.
    for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        avArray[i].~NotDefaultConstructable();
}
```

example 1: https://godbolt.org/z/7jW8Pb

---

### Example 2: std::array with std::optional

Here's an example using std::optional, which has minor overhead (about ~4 bytes per object) to achieve much more convenience:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

struct NotDefaultConstructable {
    int Value;

    NotDefaultConstructable(int val) : Value(val) {
        std::cout << "constructed: " << Value << "\n";
    };

    ~NotDefaultConstructable(){
        std::cout << "destructed: " << Value << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    // allocate enough memory on the stack for 5 instances 
    std::array<std::optional<NotDefaultConstructable>, 5> avArray;

    // use placement new to construct each instance 
    for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        avArray[i] = NotDefaultConstructable((i + 1) * 2);

    // do stuff with the instances 
    for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        std::cout << "instance: " << avArray[i].value().Value << "\n";
}
```

example 2: https://godbolt.org/z/Ynx8aE

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` is an aggregate class type which *may* have a trivial, implicitly defaulted constructor. If `T` is not default-constructible, the implicit default constructor is defined as deleted, as per [[class.ctor]/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.ctor#5.3).

As this applies in your case, you cannot construct an object of `std::array<NotDefaultConstructable, 5>` by default construction. You can, however, construct it by means of aggregate initialization:

```
#include <array>

struct NotDefaultConstructable {
    NotDefaultConstructable(int){};
};

int main() {
    std::array<NotDefaultConstructable, 3> arr{1, 2, 3};
}
```

In this sense, all elements of a `std::array` object should arguably be initialized, even if they *represent* a non-present object (yet to be "filled", if you will).

You could either find a an appropriate static vector container, such as `boost::static_vector`, or you could e.g. implement a thin wrapper around `std::array` which stores an array as above as well its runtime size. Another alternative would be to use a `std::array` of optionals:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

struct NotDefaultConstructable {
    NotDefaultConstructable(int val) : val_(val) {};
    int val_;
};

int main() {
    std::array<std::optional<NotDefaultConstructable>, 3> arr{};
    arr[1] = NotDefaultConstructable{42};
    for(const auto& element : arr) {
        if(element.has_value()) {
            std::cout << "has value: " << element.value().val_;
        }  // has value: 42
    }
}
```

where no dynamic memory allocation takes place ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)):

> If an optional contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic memory allocation ever takes place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
#include <iostream>


struct NotDefaultConstructable {
    NotDefaultConstructable(int val) {
        
    };
};

int main() {
    NotDefaultConstructable aV[5] { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 };
}
```